# Laravel 5.5 basic auth login exception

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

In Laravel 5.5, when using the built-in basic auth, failed login attempts are handled by `laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.php`:

```
throw new UnauthorizedHttpException('Basic', 'Invalid credentials.');
```

However, when debugging is turned off, this returns the generic "Whoops, something went wrong" error message.

I'm trying to edit our exception Handler (app\Exceptions\Handler.php) to return a custom JSON error when an authentication error occurs.

```
 /**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Exception  $exception
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{

    //Handle API authentication failure
    if ($exception instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\UnauthorizedHttpException) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Invalid user name or password.'], 401);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

However, this *always* returns this error message, even when the user enters valid credentials. If I comment out the `if` block, those same credentials will suddenly work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Apparently some exception is thrown if render() method on your Handler is triggered.

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo Could you be more specific?

Comment: I can't tell where it's thrown. Enable debugging, re-throw the exception and check in the trace where it's thrown.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the issue (or I've misunderstood your analysis). If I remove the `if` block, valid credentials will authenticate correctly, and only invalid credentials will return the "Whoops, something went wrong" page. When that `if` block is in place, all login attempts return the "Invalid user name or password" message.

Comment: And I'm telling you that "Invalid user name or password" wouldn't be returned if exception wasn't thrown for those "valid credentials", because the exception handler wouldn't be triggered. Re-throw the exception in that if() and see where it's thrown.

Comment: It's thrown by SessionGuard as if the credentials were invalid. Again, this only happens when the if block is in that `render()` function. The same credentials work without any error if the `if` block is not there. This is starting to sound like a bug in Laravel, but I'm not certain.

Answer (score 0):

The response must contain the appropriate header.

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{

    //Handle API authentication failure
    if ($exception instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\UnauthorizedHttpException) {
        $headers = array('WWW-Authenticate' => 'Basic');
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Invalid user name or password.'], 401);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```